# IE 11 will not print or allow print preview from web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, printing

IE keeps crashing when trying to print or do print preview of something from my web application. I am able to print in IE from other websites. I am able to print from my web app using Chrome and FF.

Here is the error message that I got from the Event Log in IE:

The program IEXPLORE.EXE version 11.0.9600.18124 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Action Center control panel.

Process ID: 4504

Start Time: 01d2d0a64c08bbef

Termination Time: 14

Application Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE

Report Id: 9bb5e04a-3c99-11e7-80e7-00505693700d

Faulting package full name:

Faulting package-relative application ID:

---

- System
- Provider

  [ Name]  Application Hang
- EventID 1002

  [ Qualifiers]  0

  Level 2

  Task 101

  Keywords 0x80000000000000
- TimeCreated

  [ SystemTime]  2017-05-19T15:19:55.000000000Z

  EventRecordID 155953

  Channel Application

  Computer XX

  Security
- EventData

  IEXPLORE.EXE

  11.0.9600.18124

  5c04

  01d2d0b33debb50e

  11

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE

  98aa5612-3ca6-11e7-80e7-00505693700d

---

**Things I have already tried:**

- Ran IE as an Administrator
- Disabled Protected Mode
- Ran IE without add-ons
- Cleared cache
- Checked that the Temp\Low folder exists (it exists)

I read that the Integrity Level on the Low folder may need to be reset. Could this be true even though I am able to print from other sites in IE?

I am unable to restart the computer as I am working on the server. It would take the site down for everyone. However, this issue is occurring on other user's computers so I can have them do a restart if necessary.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The first step in troubleshooting web browser issues is to test in noAddons Mode. Start>Run>iexplorer.exe -extoff   . If your web application involves an embedded PDF document, then Tools>Manage Addons>Show all addons>...locate your PDF view addon (activeX control) and make sure its enabled. If using Adobe PDF Reader, check the adobe website for updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone that may have this issue in the future, the problem was coming from our Bootstrap V4 css file. Below is the following style that causes the issue:

```
@media print {
   *,
   *::before,
   *::after,
   *::first-letter,
   *::first-line {
        text-shadow: none !important;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
   }
}
```

And here is how the style needs to be updated:

```
@media print {
   *,
   *::before,
   *::after,
   p::first-letter,
   div::first-letter,
   blockquote::first-letter,
   li::first-letter,
   p::first-line,
   div::first-line,
   blockquote::first-line,
   li::first-line {
          text-shadow: none !important;
          -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
          box-shadow: none !important;
   }
}
```